# Following technet guide for azurestack, running into powershell repository errors

Tags: azure, powershell, module, repository

I'm currently on step four of the technet guide, and powershell is giving me errors which I do not quite fully understand.

To me it looks like its trying to use repository BootStrap?  But my repository is PSGallery as noted by the steps.  Is the format of the "Install-Module" name parameter AzureRm.(repository)?

And as for the second error, not sure where version 1.2.11 came from as the code specified 1.4.0.

Thanks for the help! Screenshot attached of my outputs.[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-powershell-install#4-connected-install-powershell-for-azure-stack-with-internet-connectivity

Comment: found someone asking the exact same question here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a709f0ff-2e82-42d9-83c5-d1d06030bbc5/asdk-1808-azurermprofile-fails?forum=AzureStack

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Yes, the documentation was updated, and I deployed from scratch and it worked.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce your issue, the command works fine on my side. Here is some information for you to refer.

> To me it looks like its trying to use repository BootStrap? But my repository is PSGallery as noted by the steps. Is the format of the "Install-Module" name parameter AzureRm.(repository)?

It is correct, `AzureRM.BootStrapper` belongs to PSGallery , refer to this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.4.0). Note the `Minimum PowerShell version` is `5.0`. Also, it update the `0.4.0` version in `9/17/2018`, may be related.

**My powershell environment:**

[image]

**Result snippet(not complete, because it is too long):**

[image]

[image]

[image]